# Swap partition is not being swapped on automatically

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, swap

**I have Ubuntu 18.04.4, during installation I have created a 16GB swap partition. Everything worked fine until I have deleted it and created a new one because I needed that part of my disk. The new partition is never swapped on and I have to swap it on manually each time. Any ideas?**

=========================================================

**`cat /etc/fstab` output:**

> # swap was on /dev/sdb6 during installation

> UUID=7a6bcacc-80cc-43ab-a6f9-bba2ad700fd0 none

=========================================================

**`lsblk -o NAME,LABEL,SIZE,FSTYPE,MOUNTPOINT,UUID` output:**

sda                  465,8G

sda1                 100M vfat     /boot/efi 989D-9C4A

sda2                  16M

sda3               135,8G ntfs 2ECCA154CCA1175D

sda4                18,6G ext4 47814b5c-274c-419a-9cd8-fde3747b7db5

sda5                 954M ext4     /boot 8439bda4-aa66-4691-b91b-2c17a2077605

sda6               166,5G ext4     / d84635f0-058f-4756-9a44-9919896b2986

sda7                 506M ntfs 6E6CE1CA6CE18D61

**sda8                14,9G swap     [SWAP]
94a8fc28-7164-44c2-abfa-1f0a3ce8eb4f**

sda9  arch64        32,1G ext4 52dc9139-72f4-4eba-9d8b-a6f3190df6af

sda10 GAMES         96,3G ext4     /srv 604132ee-2976-4181-be11-e059fe5d96d6

=========================================================

Comment: What does `cat /etc/fstab`  and `lsblk -o NAME,LABEL,SIZE,FSTYPE,MOUNTPOINT,UUID` show? Please add output to your question.

Comment: Did you put the new entry (UUID or /dev/XXX) for the new swap partition in /etc/fstab?

Comment: @WU-TANG no I haven't, how do I do that?

Comment: Update /etc/fstab with new UID for swap: 94a8fc28-7164-44c2-abfa-1f0a3ce8eb4f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've changed the swap partition, and thus its UUID. That must be reflected in the file `/etc/fstab`:

Open a terminal and type

`sudo nano /etc/fstab`

Search for a line that looks like this:

```
UUID=7a6bcacc-80cc-43ab-a6f9-bba2ad700fd0  none  swap       sw       0       0
```

Replace that number after UUID with `94a8fc28-7164-44c2-abfa-1f0a3ce8eb4f`so it looks like this:

```
UUID=94a8fc28-7164-44c2-abfa-1f0a3ce8eb4f  none  swap       sw       0       0
```

Save it by using CRTL+X and reboot.
If you've enabled hibernate, grub needs the actual resume uuid as well.

Comment: Your swap line is incorrect. See my answer for the correct line.

Comment: Well, you are right. Thanks for the tip. I'll update my answer - still my swap works...